# matplolib: what are the units in the axes positioning [l,b,w,h] (imshow involved)?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Very simple and stupid question, which I could not find answer for; when I do manual axis positioning, like so:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(17.5,8.0))
left = 0.1
bottom = 0.03
width = 0.3
height = 0.6
ax1 = plt.axes([left, bottom, width, height])
left += (width+0.12)
ax2 = plt.axes([left, bottom, width, height])
```

these `left, bottom, width, height` variables are set in the units relative to the figure size, but which corresponds to which: is `left` and `width` ~ horizontal `fig_size` while `bottom` and `height` ~ vertical `fig_size`? My experimenting with this disproves this, and it is not clear at all, as it seems to depend on the vertical and horizontal components of the `figsize`... Shouldn't i say that `matplotlib` documentation is very unclear about it as well (neither `plt.axes`, nor `fig.add_axes` provide any useful info). So, please help?!

**EDIT**: I'll post my findings here, as maybe it would be helpful for others too... 
First of all, it seems now, that I was correct in the first place (as answers and comments confirm) and indeed `left` and `width` is measured in horizontal-`fig_size` units, while `bottom` and `height` is measured vertical-`fig_size` units - and everything is exactly the way it is shown in the first answer.

However, it is context dependent(!), in case you're doing `plt.imshow` downstream - this seems to overwrite `width`, `height` ratio and create square axes (for my data, as I have `n` by `n` matrix) with the size of `min(width, height)`. I didn't know about this behavior of the `imshow`.

Examples:

`left = 0.1 bottom = 0.03 width = 0.3 height = 0.3` with `imshow`:
[image: <code>left = 0.1 bottom = 0.03 width = 0.3 height = 0.3</code> with <code>imshow</code>]

`left = 0.1 bottom = 0.03 width = 0.3 height = 0.3` without `imshow` or any other content:

[image: <code>left = 0.1 bottom = 0.03 width = 0.3 height = 0.3</code> without <code>imshow</code> or any other content]
So the `imshow` was the source of the confusion and the "disproval".

Comment: You're correct in that the arguments to `plt.axes` are in relative figure coordinates. Why do you think that your example disproves this?

Comment: For the `imshow` problem, try adding the keyword `aspect='auto'` to `imshow`. Then it does not do anything special to try to keep the pixels square. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13384653/imshow-extent-and-aspect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `David Zwicker` says, the coordinates are relative to the figure size. If your experimenting seems to disprove this, please consider the placement of the ticks, axis labels, etc.

Let us create a third axes with the same coordinate system as the figure and show the axes areas there:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(17.5,8.0))
left = 0.1
bottom = 0.03
width = 0.3
height = 0.6

# let us create third axes with the figure coordinates:
ax3 = plt.axes([0, 0, 1, 1], frameon=False, zorder=10)

ax1 = plt.axes([left, bottom, width, height])
ax3.add_artist(plt.Rectangle((left, bottom), width, height, facecolor=(1,0,0,.5), edgecolor='none'))

left += (width+0.12)
ax2 = plt.axes([left, bottom, width, height])
ax3.add_artist(plt.Rectangle((left, bottom), width, height, facecolor=(1,0,0,.5), edgecolor='none'))
```

This gives:

[image]

The axes positions are:

```
In [37]: ax1.get_position()
Out[37]: Bbox('array([[ 0.1 ,  0.03],\n       [ 0.4 ,  0.63]])')

In [38]: ax2.get_position()
Out[38]: Bbox('array([[ 0.52,  0.03],\n       [ 0.82,  0.63]])')
```

Maybe this clarifies the positioning.

At least visually it seems that the lower edge of the axes may really be 3 % above the bottom, and the left edges 10 % and 52 % from the left edge of the figure.