# uneven axis when using pl.imshow

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am having trouble when plotting an image using pylabs imshow. Well there is no problem while plotting but my data is uneven (approx. 32*850) so when I plot it, the y axis is very short compared to the x-axis and you can see an example here [example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4mVZ.png). I just want the image to be stretched out in the y-axis so it is easier to see.

The code I started with(excluded labels and so on) is:

```
pl.figure()
pl.imshow(fom_data, interpolation='nearest')
pl.show()
```

And after googling it I tried changing to

```
pl.figure(figsize=(6,10))
```

Which only made the white parts around it larger. I then tried to write it with pyplot instead since it was easier to find people discussing the same thing:

```
fig, ax = plt.imshow(fom_data,extent=[0,850,0,32],aspect='auto')
plt.show()
```

As I found in this example: [Imshow: extent and aspect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13384653/imshow-extent-and-aspect) but then get the following error message : 'AxesImage' object is not iterable

I am obiusly no pro, but if you know where my brain is going wrong please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pyplot:

```
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(my_image)
plt.axes().set_aspect(aspect="auto") # grab the current axes to set their aspect
```