# display image with maximum width keeping an equal ratio

Tags: matplotlib

How to display an image with imshow on all the width of an axe (viewport) but keeping the ratio 'equal' ?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(8,8))
img = ax[0].imshow(np.random.random((10,10)), aspect='equal')
line = ax[1].plot([12,34],[45,78])
```

[image]

I would like that the image width be aligned on the line plot keeping an equal ratio even if that implies having blank around. My application has a zooming feature coded on the image in fact so I would to offer all the width possible for its display.

So in few words, I would like the same width as with aspect='auto' but with square pixels.
Is it possible ? Thanks.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/13390798/18624880

Comment: No, the aspect="auto" expand the horizontal axis. I would like to keep aspect equal with a larger axe width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found with a reading of [Axes class - set explicitly size (width/height) of axes in given units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44970010/axes-class-set-explicitly-size-width-height-of-axes-in-given-units)
and the use of

```
set_adjustable('datalim')
```

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(8,8))
img = ax[0].imshow(np.random.random((10,10)), aspect='equal')
ax[0].set_adjustable('datalim')
line = ax[1].plot([12,34],[45,78])
```

[image]