# Why isn't imshow displaying correctly when using custom ticks?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis, imshow, xticks

I am trying to plot heatmap with average values with x and y axes denote physical parameters.

```py
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

#.......................................................................
# URL for temp.csv https://github.com/paragkan/dyanmic-recrystallization/blob/main/temp.csv
#.......................................................................
def read_csv(xfile):
    infile = open(xfile, 'r')
    table = []
    for row in csv.reader(infile):
        table.append(row)
    infile.close() # better leave that file alone.
    for c in range (0, len(table[0])):
        for r in range(0, len(table)):
            try:
                table[r][c] = float(table[r][c])
            except:
                pass
    return table
#.......................................................................

xfile = 'temp.csv'

table = read_csv(xfile)

x = []
y = []
z = []

for i in range(0, len(table)):
    x.append(int(1/table[i][0]))
    y.append(table[i][1])
    z.append(table[i][2])

extent = [min(x), max(x), min(y), max(y)]
d = stats.binned_statistic_2d(x, y, z, statistic='mean', bins = [5, 5])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
extent = [min(x), max(x), min(y), max(y)]
# im = ax.imshow(d[0].T, cmap='RdBu_r',  interpolation='nearest', origin='lower', extent=extent)
im = ax.imshow(d[0].T, cmap='RdBu_r',  interpolation='nearest', origin='lower')

print(d[0])
print(d[1])
print(d[2])

# ax.set_xticks(d[1])
# ax.set_yticks(d[2])

cbar = ax.figure.colorbar(im, ax = ax, shrink = 1)
# average = d[0].T
# xdist = d[1]
# ydist = d[2]
# for i in range(0, len(d[1])-1):
#     for j in range(len(d[2])-1):
#         xcord = (xdist[j] + xdist[j+1])/2
#         ycord = (ydist[i] + ydist[i+1])/2
#         txtext = plt.text(xcord, ycord, round(average[i][j], 2),  fontsize = 12, ha="center", va="center", color="w")
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

#### Printed Output

```py
[[0.00658065 0.01352    0.03897    0.09360667 0.15375806]
 [       nan        nan        nan        nan        nan]
 [0.00704516 0.02388    0.11518667 0.37206333 0.69959677]
 [       nan        nan        nan        nan        nan]
 [0.00575484 0.01212    0.05937667 0.22448333 0.46173226]]
[ 923.   962.8 1002.6 1042.4 1082.2 1122. ]
[ 2.83236704  4.58410957  6.33585211  8.08759464  9.83933718 11.59107971]
```

#### Without `extent`

[image]

#### With `extent=extent`

[image]

When I use 'extent' parameter or custom axes ticks using `set_xticks`, the map is not showing correctly. Without 'extent', everything is fine but then the axes ticks are indexed as 0, 1, 2, 3. Kindly help me resolve this issue. It is also OK if someone suggests another python package to plot heatmap with binned stats, I require saved graphs to be used in a manuscript.

#### Expected Plot

What I need is, the edges of the bins in the graph should show the actual bin's dimension. If xedges are = [900, 925, 975, ..], the ticks on the x-axis should start with 900, and the next tick should be on the next bin edge showing 925. The same for y-axis.

[image]

#### [`temp.csv`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paragkan/dyanmic-recrystallization/main/temp.csv)

```
8.90472E-4,2.8323670382,0.0054
8.90472E-4,2.8903717579,0.0054
8.90472E-4,2.9483764776,0.0054
8.90472E-4,3.0063811973,0.0054
8.90472E-4,3.064385917,0.0054
8.90472E-4,3.1223906367,0.0054
8.90472E-4,3.1803953564,0.0054
8.90472E-4,3.2384000762,0.0055
8.90472E-4,3.2964047959,0.0055
8.90472E-4,3.3544095156,0.0055
8.90472E-4,3.4124142353,0.0055
8.90472E-4,3.470418955,0.0055
8.90472E-4,3.5284236747,0.0055
8.90472E-4,3.5864283944,0.0056
8.90472E-4,3.6444331141,0.0056
8.90472E-4,3.7024378338,0.0056
8.90472E-4,3.7604425536,0.0057
8.90472E-4,3.8184472733,0.0057
8.90472E-4,3.876451993,0.0057
8.90472E-4,3.9344567127,0.0058
8.90472E-4,3.9924614324,0.0058
8.90472E-4,4.0504661521,0.0059
8.90472E-4,4.1084708718,0.0059
8.90472E-4,4.1664755915,0.006
8.90472E-4,4.2244803112,0.0061
8.90472E-4,4.282485031,0.0061
8.90472E-4,4.3404897507,0.0062
8.90472E-4,4.3984944704,0.0063
8.90472E-4,4.4564991901,0.0064
8.90472E-4,4.5145039098,0.0065
8.90472E-4,4.5725086295,0.0067
8.90472E-4,4.6305133492,0.0068
8.90472E-4,4.6885180689,0.0069
8.90472E-4,4.7465227886,0.0071
8.90472E-4,4.8045275084,0.0073
8.90472E-4,4.8625322281,0.0075
8.90472E-4,4.9205369478,0.0077
8.90472E-4,4.9785416675,0.0079
8.90472E-4,5.0365463872,0.0082
8.90472E-4,5.0945511069,0.0084
8.90472E-4,5.1525558266,0.0087
8.90472E-4,5.2105605463,0.009
8.90472E-4,5.268565266,0.0094
8.90472E-4,5.3265699857,0.0097
8.90472E-4,5.3845747055,0.0101
8.90472E-4,5.4425794252,0.0105
8.90472E-4,5.5005841449,0.011
8.90472E-4,5.5585888646,0.0115
8.90472E-4,5.6165935843,0.012
8.90472E-4,5.674598304,0.0126
8.90472E-4,5.7326030237,0.0132
8.90472E-4,5.7906077434,0.0139
8.90472E-4,5.8486124631,0.0146
8.90472E-4,5.9066171829,0.0154
8.90472E-4,5.9646219026,0.0162
8.90472E-4,6.0226266223,0.0171
8.90472E-4,6.080631342,0.018
8.90472E-4,6.1386360617,0.019
8.90472E-4,6.1966407814,0.0201
8.90472E-4,6.2546455011,0.0213
8.90472E-4,6.3126502208,0.0225
8.90472E-4,6.3706549405,0.0238
8.90472E-4,6.4286596603,0.0252
8.90472E-4,6.48666438,0.0266
8.90472E-4,6.5446690997,0.0282
8.90472E-4,6.6026738194,0.0298
8.90472E-4,6.6606785391,0.0316
8.90472E-4,6.7186832588,0.0334
8.90472E-4,6.7766879785,0.0354
8.90472E-4,6.8346926982,0.0375
8.90472E-4,6.8926974179,0.0397
8.90472E-4,6.9507021376,0.042
8.90472E-4,7.0087068574,0.0444
8.90472E-4,7.0667115771,0.047
8.90472E-4,7.1247162968,0.0497
8.90472E-4,7.1827210165,0.0525
8.90472E-4,7.2407257362,0.0555
8.90472E-4,7.2987304559,0.0586
8.90472E-4,7.3567351756,0.0619
8.90472E-4,7.4147398953,0.0654
8.90472E-4,7.472744615,0.069
8.90472E-4,7.5307493348,0.0727
8.90472E-4,7.5887540545,0.0766
8.90472E-4,7.6467587742,0.0807
8.90472E-4,7.7047634939,0.085
8.90472E-4,7.7627682136,0.0894
8.90472E-4,7.8207729333,0.094
8.90472E-4,7.878777653,0.0988
8.90472E-4,7.9367823727,0.1038
8.90472E-4,7.9947870924,0.1089
8.90472E-4,8.0527918122,0.1142
8.90472E-4,8.1107965319,0.1197
8.90472E-4,8.1688012516,0.1255
8.90472E-4,8.2268059713,0.1313
8.90472E-4,8.284810691,0.1374
8.90472E-4,8.3428154107,0.1437
8.90472E-4,8.4008201304,0.1501
8.90472E-4,8.4588248501,0.1567
8.90472E-4,8.5168295698,0.1635
8.90472E-4,8.5748342895,0.1705
8.90472E-4,8.6328390093,0.1776
8.90472E-4,8.690843729,0.1849
8.90472E-4,8.7488484487,0.1924
8.90472E-4,8.8068531684,0.2
8.90472E-4,8.8648578881,0.2078
8.90472E-4,8.9228626078,0.2157
8.90472E-4,8.9808673275,0.2238
8.90472E-4,9.0388720472,0.232
8.90472E-4,9.0968767669,0.2403
8.90472E-4,9.1548814867,0.2487
8.90472E-4,9.2128862064,0.2572
8.90472E-4,9.2708909261,0.2658
8.90472E-4,9.3288956458,0.2745
8.90472E-4,9.3869003655,0.2833
8.90472E-4,9.4449050852,0.2921
8.90472E-4,9.5029098049,0.301
8.90472E-4,9.5609145246,0.3099
8.90472E-4,9.6189192443,0.3189
8.90472E-4,9.6769239641,0.3278
8.90472E-4,9.7349286838,0.3367
8.90472E-4,9.7929334035,0.3457
8.90472E-4,9.8509381232,0.3545
8.90472E-4,9.9089428429,0.3634
8.90472E-4,9.9669475626,0.3721
8.90472E-4,10.0249522823,0.3808
8.90472E-4,10.082957002,0.3894
8.90472E-4,10.1409617217,0.3979
8.90472E-4,10.1989664414,0.4062
8.90472E-4,10.2569711612,0.4144
8.90472E-4,10.3149758809,0.4224
8.90472E-4,10.3729806006,0.4303
8.90472E-4,10.4309853203,0.438
8.90472E-4,10.48899004,0.4454
8.90472E-4,10.5469947597,0.4526
8.90472E-4,10.6049994794,0.4596
8.90472E-4,10.6630041991,0.4664
8.90472E-4,10.7210089188,0.4728
8.90472E-4,10.7790136386,0.479
8.90472E-4,10.8370183583,0.4849
8.90472E-4,10.895023078,0.4905
8.90472E-4,10.9530277977,0.4957
8.90472E-4,11.0110325174,0.5007
8.90472E-4,11.0690372371,0.5052
8.90472E-4,11.1270419568,0.5095
8.90472E-4,11.1850466765,0.5133
8.90472E-4,11.2430513962,0.5168
8.90472E-4,11.301056116,0.5199
8.90472E-4,11.3590608357,0.5226
8.90472E-4,11.4170655554,0.5249
8.90472E-4,11.4750702751,0.5268
8.90472E-4,11.5330749948,0.5283
8.90472E-4,11.5910797145,0.5294
9.775171E-4,2.8323670382,0.0056
9.775171E-4,2.8903717579,0.0057
9.775171E-4,2.9483764776,0.0057
9.775171E-4,3.0063811973,0.0057
9.775171E-4,3.064385917,0.0058
9.775171E-4,3.1223906367,0.0058
9.775171E-4,3.1803953564,0.0059
9.775171E-4,3.2384000762,0.0059
9.775171E-4,3.2964047959,0.006
9.775171E-4,3.3544095156,0.0061
9.775171E-4,3.4124142353,0.0061
9.775171E-4,3.470418955,0.0062
9.775171E-4,3.5284236747,0.0063
9.775171E-4,3.5864283944,0.0064
9.775171E-4,3.6444331141,0.0065
9.775171E-4,3.7024378338,0.0066
9.775171E-4,3.7604425536,0.0067
9.775171E-4,3.8184472733,0.0069
9.775171E-4,3.876451993,0.007
9.775171E-4,3.9344567127,0.0072
9.775171E-4,3.9924614324,0.0074
9.775171E-4,4.0504661521,0.0075
9.775171E-4,4.1084708718,0.0078
9.775171E-4,4.1664755915,0.008
9.775171E-4,4.2244803112,0.0082
9.775171E-4,4.282485031,0.0085
9.775171E-4,4.3404897507,0.0087
9.775171E-4,4.3984944704,0.009
9.775171E-4,4.4564991901,0.0094
9.775171E-4,4.5145039098,0.0097
9.775171E-4,4.5725086295,0.0101
9.775171E-4,4.6305133492,0.0105
9.775171E-4,4.6885180689,0.011
9.775171E-4,4.7465227886,0.0114
9.775171E-4,4.8045275084,0.0119
9.775171E-4,4.8625322281,0.0125
9.775171E-4,4.9205369478,0.0131
9.775171E-4,4.9785416675,0.0137
9.775171E-4,5.0365463872,0.0144
9.775171E-4,5.0945511069,0.0151
9.775171E-4,5.1525558266,0.0159
9.775171E-4,5.2105605463,0.0167
9.775171E-4,5.268565266,0.0176
9.775171E-4,5.3265699857,0.0185
9.775171E-4,5.3845747055,0.0195
9.775171E-4,5.4425794252,0.0206
9.775171E-4,5.5005841449,0.0217
9.775171E-4,5.5585888646,0.0229
9.775171E-4,5.6165935843,0.0242
9.775171E-4,5.674598304,0.0256
9.775171E-4,5.7326030237,0.0271
9.775171E-4,5.7906077434,0.0286
9.775171E-4,5.8486124631,0.0302
9.775171E-4,5.9066171829,0.032
9.775171E-4,5.9646219026,0.0338
9.775171E-4,6.0226266223,0.0358
9.775171E-4,6.080631342,0.0378
9.775171E-4,6.1386360617,0.04
9.775171E-4,6.1966407814,0.0423
9.775171E-4,6.2546455011,0.0447
9.775171E-4,6.3126502208,0.0473
9.775171E-4,6.3706549405,0.05
9.775171E-4,6.4286596603,0.0528
9.775171E-4,6.48666438,0.0558
9.775171E-4,6.5446690997,0.0589
9.775171E-4,6.6026738194,0.0622
9.775171E-4,6.6606785391,0.0657
9.775171E-4,6.7186832588,0.0693
9.775171E-4,6.7766879785,0.0731
9.775171E-4,6.8346926982,0.077
9.775171E-4,6.8926974179,0.0812
9.775171E-4,6.9507021376,0.0855
9.775171E-4,7.0087068574,0.09
9.775171E-4,7.0667115771,0.0947
9.775171E-4,7.1247162968,0.0997
9.775171E-4,7.1827210165,0.1048
9.775171E-4,7.2407257362,0.1101
9.775171E-4,7.2987304559,0.1156
9.775171E-4,7.3567351756,0.1214
9.775171E-4,7.4147398953,0.1274
9.775171E-4,7.472744615,0.1336
9.775171E-4,7.5307493348,0.14
9.775171E-4,7.5887540545,0.1466
9.775171E-4,7.6467587742,0.1535
9.775171E-4,7.7047634939,0.1606
9.775171E-4,7.7627682136,0.168
9.775171E-4,7.8207729333,0.1755
9.775171E-4,7.878777653,0.1833
9.775171E-4,7.9367823727,0.1914
9.775171E-4,7.9947870924,0.1997
9.775171E-4,8.0527918122,0.2082
9.775171E-4,8.1107965319,0.2169
9.775171E-4,8.1688012516,0.2259
9.775171E-4,8.2268059713,0.2351
9.775171E-4,8.284810691,0.2445
9.775171E-4,8.3428154107,0.2542
9.775171E-4,8.4008201304,0.264
9.775171E-4,8.4588248501,0.2741
9.775171E-4,8.5168295698,0.2844
9.775171E-4,8.5748342895,0.2948
9.775171E-4,8.6328390093,0.3055
9.775171E-4,8.690843729,0.3164
9.775171E-4,8.7488484487,0.3274
9.775171E-4,8.8068531684,0.3386
9.775171E-4,8.8648578881,0.35
9.775171E-4,8.9228626078,0.3615
9.775171E-4,8.9808673275,0.3732
9.775171E-4,9.0388720472,0.3849
9.775171E-4,9.0968767669,0.3968
9.775171E-4,9.1548814867,0.4088
9.775171E-4,9.2128862064,0.4209
9.775171E-4,9.2708909261,0.4331
9.775171E-4,9.3288956458,0.4453
9.775171E-4,9.3869003655,0.4576
9.775171E-4,9.4449050852,0.4699
9.775171E-4,9.5029098049,0.4823
9.775171E-4,9.5609145246,0.4946
9.775171E-4,9.6189192443,0.5069
9.775171E-4,9.6769239641,0.5192
9.775171E-4,9.7349286838,0.5315
9.775171E-4,9.7929334035,0.5436
9.775171E-4,9.8509381232,0.5557
9.775171E-4,9.9089428429,0.5677
9.775171E-4,9.9669475626,0.5796
9.775171E-4,10.0249522823,0.5913
9.775171E-4,10.082957002,0.6028
9.775171E-4,10.1409617217,0.6142
9.775171E-4,10.1989664414,0.6254
9.775171E-4,10.2569711612,0.6364
9.775171E-4,10.3149758809,0.6471
9.775171E-4,10.3729806006,0.6576
9.775171E-4,10.4309853203,0.6678
9.775171E-4,10.48899004,0.6778
9.775171E-4,10.5469947597,0.6874
9.775171E-4,10.6049994794,0.6967
9.775171E-4,10.6630041991,0.7056
9.775171E-4,10.7210089188,0.7142
9.775171E-4,10.7790136386,0.7225
9.775171E-4,10.8370183583,0.7303
9.775171E-4,10.895023078,0.7377
9.775171E-4,10.9530277977,0.7448
9.775171E-4,11.0110325174,0.7514
9.775171E-4,11.0690372371,0.7575
9.775171E-4,11.1270419568,0.7632
9.775171E-4,11.1850466765,0.7684
9.775171E-4,11.2430513962,0.7732
9.775171E-4,11.301056116,0.7774
9.775171E-4,11.3590608357,0.7812
9.775171E-4,11.4170655554,0.7845
9.775171E-4,11.4750702751,0.7873
9.775171E-4,11.5330749948,0.7895
9.775171E-4,11.5910797145,0.7913
0.0010834236,2.8323670382,0.0057
0.0010834236,2.8903717579,0.0057
0.0010834236,2.9483764776,0.0057
0.0010834236,3.0063811973,0.0058
0.0010834236,3.064385917,0.0058
0.0010834236,3.1223906367,0.0058
0.0010834236,3.1803953564,0.0059
0.0010834236,3.2384000762,0.0059
0.0010834236,3.2964047959,0.006
0.0010834236,3.3544095156,0.006
0.0010834236,3.4124142353,0.0061
0.0010834236,3.470418955,0.0061
0.0010834236,3.5284236747,0.0062
0.0010834236,3.5864283944,0.0062
0.0010834236,3.6444331141,0.0063
0.0010834236,3.7024378338,0.0064
0.0010834236,3.7604425536,0.0065
0.0010834236,3.8184472733,0.0065
0.0010834236,3.876451993,0.0066
0.0010834236,3.9344567127,0.0067
0.0010834236,3.9924614324,0.0068
0.0010834236,4.0504661521,0.0069
0.0010834236,4.1084708718,0.007
0.0010834236,4.1664755915,0.0072
0.0010834236,4.2244803112,0.0073
0.0010834236,4.282485031,0.0074
0.0010834236,4.3404897507,0.0076
0.0010834236,4.3984944704,0.0077
0.0010834236,4.4564991901,0.0079
0.0010834236,4.5145039098,0.0081
0.0010834236,4.5725086295,0.0082
0.0010834236,4.6305133492,0.0084
0.0010834236,4.6885180689,0.0086
0.0010834236,4.7465227886,0.0089
0.0010834236,4.8045275084,0.0091
0.0010834236,4.8625322281,0.0093
0.0010834236,4.9205369478,0.0096
0.0010834236,4.9785416675,0.0098
0.0010834236,5.0365463872,0.0101
0.0010834236,5.0945511069,0.0104
0.0010834236,5.1525558266,0.0107
0.0010834236,5.2105605463,0.0111
0.0010834236,5.268565266,0.0114
0.0010834236,5.3265699857,0.0118
0.0010834236,5.3845747055,0.0122
0.0010834236,5.4425794252,0.0126
0.0010834236,5.5005841449,0.013
0.0010834236,5.5585888646,0.0134
0.0010834236,5.6165935843,0.0139
0.0010834236,5.674598304,0.0144
0.0010834236,5.7326030237,0.0149
0.0010834236,5.7906077434,0.0154
0.0010834236,5.8486124631,0.016
0.0010834236,5.9066171829,0.0165
0.0010834236,5.9646219026,0.0171
0.0010834236,6.0226266223,0.0178
0.0010834236,6.080631342,0.0184
0.0010834236,6.1386360617,0.0191
0.0010834236,6.1966407814,0.0198
0.0010834236,6.2546455011,0.0206
0.0010834236,6.3126502208,0.0213
0.0010834236,6.3706549405,0.0221
0.0010834236,6.4286596603,0.023
0.0010834236,6.48666438,0.0238
0.0010834236,6.5446690997,0.0247
0.0010834236,6.6026738194,0.0257
0.0010834236,6.6606785391,0.0266
0.0010834236,6.7186832588,0.0276
0.0010834236,6.7766879785,0.0287
0.0010834236,6.8346926982,0.0297
0.0010834236,6.8926974179,0.0308
0.0010834236,6.9507021376,0.032
0.0010834236,7.0087068574,0.0332
0.0010834236,7.0667115771,0.0344
0.0010834236,7.1247162968,0.0356
0.0010834236,7.1827210165,0.0369
0.0010834236,7.2407257362,0.0382
0.0010834236,7.2987304559,0.0396
0.0010834236,7.3567351756,0.041
0.0010834236,7.4147398953,0.0425
0.0010834236,7.472744615,0.0439
0.0010834236,7.5307493348,0.0455
0.0010834236,7.5887540545,0.047
0.0010834236,7.6467587742,0.0486
0.0010834236,7.7047634939,0.0502
0.0010834236,7.7627682136,0.0519
0.0010834236,7.8207729333,0.0536
0.0010834236,7.878777653,0.0554
0.0010834236,7.9367823727,0.0571
0.0010834236,7.9947870924,0.059
0.0010834236,8.0527918122,0.0608
0.0010834236,8.1107965319,0.0627
0.0010834236,8.1688012516,0.0646
0.0010834236,8.2268059713,0.0666
0.0010834236,8.284810691,0.0685
0.0010834236,8.3428154107,0.0705
0.0010834236,8.4008201304,0.0726
0.0010834236,8.4588248501,0.0747
0.0010834236,8.5168295698,0.0768
0.0010834236,8.5748342895,0.0789
0.0010834236,8.6328390093,0.081
0.0010834236,8.690843729,0.0832
0.0010834236,8.7488484487,0.0854
0.0010834236,8.8068531684,0.0876
0.0010834236,8.8648578881,0.0898
0.0010834236,8.9228626078,0.092
0.0010834236,8.9808673275,0.0943
0.0010834236,9.0388720472,0.0966
0.0010834236,9.0968767669,0.0988
0.0010834236,9.1548814867,0.1011
0.0010834236,9.2128862064,0.1034
0.0010834236,9.2708909261,0.1057
0.0010834236,9.3288956458,0.108
0.0010834236,9.3869003655,0.1103
0.0010834236,9.4449050852,0.1125
0.0010834236,9.5029098049,0.1148
0.0010834236,9.5609145246,0.1171
0.0010834236,9.6189192443,0.1193
0.0010834236,9.6769239641,0.1216
0.0010834236,9.7349286838,0.1238
0.0010834236,9.7929334035,0.126
0.0010834236,9.8509381232,0.1282
0.0010834236,9.9089428429,0.1303
0.0010834236,9.9669475626,0.1324
0.0010834236,10.0249522823,0.1345
0.0010834236,10.082957002,0.1366
0.0010834236,10.1409617217,0.1386
0.0010834236,10.1989664414,0.1406
0.0010834236,10.2569711612,0.1425
0.0010834236,10.3149758809,0.1444
0.0010834236,10.3729806006,0.1463
0.0010834236,10.4309853203,0.1481
0.0010834236,10.48899004,0.1498
0.0010834236,10.5469947597,0.1515
0.0010834236,10.6049994794,0.1532
0.0010834236,10.6630041991,0.1547
0.0010834236,10.7210089188,0.1563
0.0010834236,10.7790136386,0.1577
0.0010834236,10.8370183583,0.1591
0.0010834236,10.895023078,0.1604
0.0010834236,10.9530277977,0.1617
0.0010834236,11.0110325174,0.1629
0.0010834236,11.0690372371,0.164
0.0010834236,11.1270419568,0.165
0.0010834236,11.1850466765,0.166
0.0010834236,11.2430513962,0.1668
0.0010834236,11.301056116,0.1676
0.0010834236,11.3590608357,0.1684
0.0010834236,11.4170655554,0.169
0.0010834236,11.4750702751,0.1695
0.0010834236,11.5330749948,0.17
0.0010834236,11.5910797145,0.1704
```

Comment: What I need is, the edges of the bins in the graph should show the actual bin's dimension. If xedges are = [900, 925, 975, ..], the ticks on the x-axis should start with 900, and the next tick should be on the next bin edge showing 925. The same for y-axis.

Comment: https://github.com/paragkan/dyanmic-recrystallization/blob/main/Figure_1.png                This is the desired output of the above question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "aspect" option in imshow to force the image to return to the correct aspect ratio. To get a square image, the aspect ratio would need to be the inverse of the ratio of the two side lengths. See also: [Imshow: extent and aspect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13384653/imshow-extent-and-aspect)

In your case your x length is about 200 and your y length is about 10, so you'd want to set an aspect of about 20.

Comment: `aspect=dx/dy` gives you _exactly_ a square box. I'd like to warn the OP that changing `aspect` is acceptable IFF the units on the axes are different, if the units (e.g., km and km) are the same is better to have `aspect=1` (the default)

Comment: Let me try. Thanks for your help.